# Multiple Regex on String

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How can I apply multiple regexs to a single string?

For instance, a user inputs the following into a text area:

```
red bird
blue cat
black dog
```

and I want to replace each carriage return with a comma and each space with an underscore so the final string reads as red_bird,blue_cat,black_dog.

I've tried variations in syntax along the lines of the following so far:

```
function formatTextArea() {
    var textString = document.getElementById('userinput').value;

    var formatText = textString.replace(
        new RegExp( "\\n", "g" ),",",
        new RegExp( "\\s", "g"),"_");

    alert(formatText);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain the replacements. Every application of the replace method retuns a string, so on that string you can apply replace again. Like:

```
function formatTextArea() {
    var textString = document.getElementById('userinput').value;

    var formatText = 
         textString.replace(/\n/g,",")
                   .replace(/\s/g,"_");

    alert(formatText);
}
```

There's no need for all these new Regular Expression Objects by the way. Use Regular Expression literals (like `/\n/g` in the above).

Alternatively you can use a lambda for the replacement

```js
const str = `red bird
blue cat
black dog`;
console.log(str.replace(/[\n\s]/g, a => /\n/.test(a) ? "," : "_"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
formatText = textString.replace(/\n/g,',').replace(/\s/g,'_');
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, chaining is good enough for something as simple as what you're asking.  However, if you want this to be more dynamic, you can use a replacer function as the second argument:

```
function formatTextArea() {
    var textString = document.getElementById('userinput').value;

    var formatText = textString.replace(/\n|\s/g, function ($0) {
        if ($0 === "\n")
            return ",";
        else if ($0 === " ")
            return "_";
    }
    alert(formatText);
}
```

Using a replacer function will allow you to be dynamic without having to chain together calls to `replace()`. It may also be marginally faster (regex parser is invoked only once). Be aware that `\s` will match more than just the space character, though :-)  For the purposes of your question, this would be good enough:

```
var formatText = textString.replace(/\n|\s/g, function ($0) {
    return $0 == "\n" ? "," : "_";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexp object have their own literal notation, using forward slashes, meaning that backslashes don't have to be escaped. For example, `/\n/g` is equivalent to `new RegExp('\\n','g')`.

```
function formatTextArea()
{
    var textString = document.getElementById('userinput').value;

    textString = textString.replace(/\n/g,",").replace(/\s/g,"_");

    alert(textString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textString = "red blue\nhack bye\ntest rt\n";
var formatText = textString.replace(new RegExp( "\\n", "g" ),",").replace(new RegExp( "\\s", "g"),"_");
alert(formatText);
```

Answer (score -3):

Include http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace:527 and then

```
input = str_replace("\\n", ',', input);
input = str_replace(' ', '_', input);
```

Comment: Why should you use *this*? JavaScript has a native [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) function.

Comment: Is easy to see people that know a language, love it and underestimate others.